# Play bytestream on client site with web audio api

Tags: asp.net, web-audio-api

I'm sending an stereo audiofile (WAV) via websockets and want to play it via the Web Audio Api. The Serversite technology is asp.net.
Currently i have this:

```
 ws.onmessage = function(evt) {

        var d2 = new DataView(evt.data);

        var data = new Float32Array(d2.byteLength / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
        for (var jj = 0; jj < data.length; ++jj) {
            data[jj] = d2.getFloat32(jj * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, true);
        }


        var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, 44100);
        buffer.getChannelData(0).set(data);

        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.start(startTime);
        source.connect(context.destination);

        startTime += buffer.duration;

    }
```

With this i can hear the song but with A LOT of noise... i believe this might be because it is an stereo file and i only use 1 channel? 
If yes, how could i do it with two channels? I tried some things but the result was always the same or worse.

And i have another problem in understanding why it is working with Float32Array? In my first approach i used Uint8Array because i'm sending bytes to the client so i thought i would need Uint8Array to get the same values i send. But with Uint8Array i just hear noise and nothing from the song at all.

thanks for your help in advance!

Best Regards,
metabolic

Comment: It's working with `Float32Array` because that's what the Web Audio API uses for `AudioBuffer` instances. Can you tell me a bit more about the data you're sending to the client? Are they actually `.wav` buffers complete with RIFF headers, or is it just LPCM data?

Comment: Also: the Web Audio API wants floats with a nominal range of +1 to -1. So depending on what you're sending, you'll probably need to do a bit of math to squeeze your values in to that range.

Comment: ah thank you very much! i did not fully understand why float32 is necessary and that it needs the values between -1 and 1. now it's working fine.

Comment: it works now but what i noticed is, that there are some "clicks" in the audio when transmitted. Could this be because the audiobuffers are connected after each other and on every overlap there is a click?

Comment: They way you're doing the timing looks okay to me. I don't think there should be any real overlap (or gap). Could be something in the buffers themselves. Maybe as a test, try just storing them all in one big array, then loop through and create a single `AudioBuffer` from them. Then see if that has clicks or pops. If it does, your problem is probably in the buffers (or your math), but not the way you're doing the timing.