# Playback with Web Audio api very slow

Tags: web-audio-api

I have a very strange problem:

I'm playing a wav with the web audio api the following way:

```
        var d2 = new DataView(evt.data);

        var data = new Float32Array(d2.byteLength / Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
        for (var jj = 0; jj < data.length; ++jj) {
            data[jj] = d2.getFloat32(jj * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, true);
        }

        var buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, 44100);
        buffer.getChannelData(0).set(data);

        source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.start(startTime);
        source.connect(context.destination);

        startTime += buffer.duration;
```

This worked perfectly fine but now the playback speed is very slow...

I did not change anything on the code. The only thing that changed was that i recently changed my OS from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1.
Could there be any relation to this problem?

I tried it in Chrome and Firefox and both have the same behaviour.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

I'm sending float values to the client because as i learned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27459436/play-bytestream-on-client-site-with-web-audio-api) the Web Audio Api needs float values between -1 an 1 to process the audio data correct.
When i remove the float values and start sending PCM Data again the playback speed is normal. It's full of noise again but the speed is normal...

I would really appreciate any input which might help me to figure out this strange problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check the sample-rate of the AudioContext, and put it instead of the hard-coded 44100 value. Also, check the number of channels of you buffer. Your code, as it is, will only work on mono.

Comment: Thank you! it was the samplingrate... but not as i expected. there seams to be a problem with my soundcard/sounddrivers... i had to double the samplingrate in my output device to 88200. Do you have an idea why only the web audio api seams to have a problem with the driver?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox both use the default audio output device sample rate, so it's necessary to have code that adapts to any sample rate. Are you sure your source is not interleaved stereo? Have you checked the size of a sample in your source? Is it 32bits or 16bits?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, playing at 88200 seemed to solve it.

But as @padenot indicated, I tried splitting up the left and right channel like this (assuming I was dealing with interleaved stereo):

```
var floatsLeft = new Float32Array(samples.length/2);
var floatsRight = new Float32Array(samples.length/2);

for (var i = samples.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(i%2 == 0)
    floatsLeft[i/2] = samples[i];
  else
    floatsRight[(i-1)/2] = samples[i];
};

var audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(2, samples.length/2, audioContext.sampleRate)
var bufferSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();

audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(floatsLeft);
audioBuffer.getChannelData(1).set(floatsRight);

bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
bufferSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
bufferSource.start(0);
```

And now it works perfectly. And probably in stereo too!